# Pass command line parameters to perl via file?

Tags: perl

Could command lines parameters been saved to a file and then pass the file to perl to parse out the options? Like response file (prefix the name with @) for some Microsoft tools.

Comment: Like `perl $(cat options.txt) prog.pl`?

Comment: This is an odd request. What problem are you trying to solve with this? There may be a better solution.

Comment: `xargs -a file.txt perl ...` handles whitespace in the arguments unlike @melpomene's solution. If you need newlines in the arguments, look at `xargs -0`. This is in no way specific to Perl (but somewhat specific to a Unux-like shell).

Comment: @schwern I am passing parameters to perl in Windows command promptin which single quote cannot separate parameters instead double quotes are used. This makes passing string expression via command inconvenient. Response file might solve this.

Comment: @Thomson Try using `q[]` and `qq[]` instead. Which parameters are you passing to perl that need strings? Do you mean to `perl` itself, or to the program as `@ARGV`? An example would help clear things up.

Comment: @Schwern yes, `qq[]` or `qq//` is a good workaround if response file is not supported. I am trying to pass expression to perl via command line, like `perl -e 'print "\n"'`, and Windows command prompt makes using double quotes a little hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to pass expression to perl via command line, like perl -e 'print "\n"', and Windows command prompt makes using double quotes a little hard.

There are several solutions, from most to least preferable.

**Write your program to a file**

If your one liner is too big or complicated, write it to a file and run it. This avoids messing with shell escapes. You can reuse it and debug it and work in a real editor.

```
perl path\to\some_program
```

Command line options to perl can be put on the otherwise useless on Windows `#!` line. Here's an example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak -p

# -i.bak Backs up the file.
# -p Puts each line into $_ and writes out the new value of $_.
# So this changes all instances in a file of " with '.
s{"}{'}g;
```

**Use alternative quote delimiters**

[Perl has a slew of alternative ways to write quotes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators). Use them instead.  This is good for both one liners as well as things like `q[<tag key='value'>]`.

```
perl -e "print qq[\n]"
```

**Escape the quote**

[`^` is the `cmd.exe` escape character](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html). So `^"` is treated as a literal quote.

```
perl -e "print ^"\n^""
```

Pretty yucky. I'd prefer using `qq[]` and reserve `^"` for when you need to print a literal quote.

```
perl -e "print qq[^"\n]"
```

**Use the ASCII code**

[The ASCII and UTF-8 hex code for `"` is 22](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ascii+table&t=ffab).  You can supply this to Perl with `qq[\x22]`.

```
perl -e "print qq[\x22\n]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into a string and then use

```
    use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptionsFromString);
    $ret = GetOptionsFromString($string, ...);
```

to parse the options from that.

Comment: Note that these are options to your script, not perl itself.